# ClientCacheConfiguration is not saved to table

Tags: ignite

Was using CacheConfiguration in Ignite until I stuck with issue on how to authenticate.
Because of that I was starting to change the CacheConfiguration to clientCacheConfiguration. However after converting it to CacheConfiguration I started to notice that it
does not able to save into table because it lack of method setIndexedTypes eg.
Before

```
CacheConfiguration<String, IgniteParRate> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();
cacheCfg.setName(APIConstants.CACHE_PARRATES);
cacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(String.class, IgniteParRate.class);
```

New

```
ClientCacheConfiguration cacheCfg = new ClientCacheConfiguration();
cacheCfg.setName(APIConstants.CACHE_PARRATES);
//cacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(String.class, IgniteParRate.class);  --> this is not provided
```

I still need the table to be populated so it easier for us to verify ( using Client IDE like DBeaver)
Any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to create tables/cache dynamically using the thin-client, you'll need to use the `setQueryEntities()` method to define the columns available to SQL "manually". (Passing in the classes with annotations is basically a shortcut for defining the query entities.) I'm not sure why `setIndexedTypes()` isn't available in the thin-client; maybe a question for the developer mailing list.

Alternatively, you can define your caches/tables in advance using a thick client. They'll still be available when using the thin-client.

Comment: was able to solve my authentication issue, so decided not to continue converting CacheConfiguration to clientConfiguration. However, if need to continue with ClientConfiguration, this answer is the only lead.  Approving this answer  because of that.  For solving using CacheConfiguration please follow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610118/implementing-authentication-in-ignitedb/59659397#59659397

Answer (score 1):

To add to existing answer, you can also try to use cache templates for that.
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-template

Pre-configure templates, use them when creating caches from thin client.