# Implementing Authentication in IgniteDB

Tags: security, authentication, ignite

I just configured authentication in IgniteDB ( a specific server, not a localhost )
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/advanced-security

However I encountered some issue while trying to connect. Where should I provide the credential?

```
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
String ipList = appConfig.getIgniteIPAddressList();
List<String> addressList= Arrays.asList(ipList.split(";"));
ipFinder.setAddresses(addressList);
spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("IgnitePod");
cfg.setClientMode(true);
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
Ignite ignite =  Ignition.start(cfg);
```

Anybody has idea on implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve my own problem by creating my own CustomTCPDiscoveryAPI.
First, create this class :

```
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteException;
import org.apache.ignite.cluster.ClusterNode;
import org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteNodeAttributes;
import org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.security.SecurityContext;
import org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteProductVersion;
import org.apache.ignite.plugin.security.SecurityCredentials;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.DiscoverySpiNodeAuthenticator;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi;

import java.util.Map;

public class CustomTcpDiscoverySpi extends TcpDiscoverySpi implements DiscoverySpiNodeAuthenticator {
    SecurityCredentials securityCredentials;
    public CustomTcpDiscoverySpi(final SecurityCredentials securityCredentials) {
        this.securityCredentials = securityCredentials;
        this.setAuthenticator(this);
    }

    @Override
    public SecurityContext authenticateNode(ClusterNode clusterNode, SecurityCredentials securityCredentials) throws IgniteException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isGlobalNodeAuthentication() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNodeAttributes(final Map<String, Object> attrs, final IgniteProductVersion ver) {
        attrs.put(IgniteNodeAttributes.ATTR_SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, this.securityCredentials);
        super.setNodeAttributes(attrs, ver);
    }
}
```

And then, use it like below :

```
    SecurityCredentials cred = new SecurityCredentials();
    cred.setLogin(appConfig.getIgniteUser());
    cred.setPassword(appConfig.getIgnitePassword());
    CustomTcpDiscoverySpi spi =  new CustomTcpDiscoverySpi(cred);
    //TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi(); - > removed to use the CustomTCPDiscovery
    TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
    String ipList = appConfig.getIgniteIPAddressList();
    List<String> addressList= Arrays.asList(ipList.split(";"));
    ipFinder.setAddresses(addressList);
    spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("IgnitePod");
    cfg.setClientMode(true);
    cfg.setAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    // Ignite persistence configuration.
    DataStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
    // Enabling the persistence.
    storageCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    // Applying settings.
    // tests
    cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageCfg);
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
    Ignite ignite =  Ignition.start(cfg);
```

Hope this helps other people who stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/advanced-security

Describes how to configure the authentication via username and password for THIN connections only (JDBC, ODBC).

You can create users using SQL commands like next:

https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-user

You can provide credentials to thin client connection string using its properties:

https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/connection-string-and-dsn#section-supported-arguments
https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver#section-additional-connection-string-examples

Please also check that you have Ignite persistence configured.

Answer (score 2):

As [Andrei notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59610797/2998), Ignite only authenticates thin clients by default, and even then only when persistence is enabled. If you need to have thick-clients authenticate also, you can do this using a [plugin](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/plugins). Third-party, commercial solutions also exist.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Ignite does not provide these kinds of security capabilities with its open-source version. One can either implement it on your own or use commercial Gridgain distribution.

Here are the steps to implement a custom security plugin.

One would need to implement `GridSecurityProcessor` which would be used to authenticate the joining node.

In `GridSecurityProcessor`, you would have to implement `authenticateNode()` api as follows

```
public SecurityContext authenticateNode(ClusterNode node, SecurityCredentials cred) throws IgniteCheckedException {

        SecurityCredentials userSecurityCredentials;

        if (securityPluginConfiguration != null) {
            if ((userSecurityCredentials = securityPluginConfiguration.getSecurityCredentials()) != null) {
                return userSecurityCredentials.equals(cred) ? new SecurityContextImpl() : null;
            }
            if (cred == null && userSecurityCredentials == null) {
                return new SecurityContextImpl();
            }
        }

        if (cred == null)
            return new SecurityContextImpl();

        return null;

    }
```

Also, you would need to extend `TcpDiscoverySpi` to pass the user credentials during `initLocalNode()` as follows

```
@Override
    protected void initLocalNode(int srvPort, boolean addExtAddrAttr) {
        try {
            super.initLocalNode(srvPort, addExtAddrAttr);
            this.setSecurityCredentials();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
private void setSecurityCredentials() {
        if (securityCredentials != null) {

            Map<String,Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(locNode.getAttributes());
            attributes.put(IgniteNodeAttributes.ATTR_SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, securityCredentials);
            this.locNode.setAttributes(attributes);
        }
    }
```

You can follow the link given below to get detailed steps that can be followed to write a custom security plugin and its usage.

https://www.bugdbug.com/post/how-to-secure-apache-ignite-cluster

Answer (score 0):

The only option for peer-authenticating server nodes which is available in vanilla Apache Ignite is SSL+certificates.